# Scripting: insert an additional #include after the last #include in many, many files

Tags: c, regex, bash, sed

For a second I was hoping to get away with `sed`'s `a\` command, but `sed` (in my hands, anyway) isn't really a fan of keeping state (inserts after every #include).

So is there a way to do this with `sed`? Is there a *smart* way of doing this?

I'll resort to writing a regular Python/Ruby script if that's the way to go, but this seems to be a problem someone has probably bumped into somewhere, sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before applying your sed you can reverse the file line by line with the command tac and then let sed do an *insert* instead of append. And of course make sure that sed only does this insert once. Like this:

```
tac file | sed '1,/#include/ {/#include/i\
#include whatever
}' | tac
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have any multi-line comments before your main program starts:

```
 awk '!f && /^ *[a-zA-Z]/{print "#include<newfile.h>";f=1;}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i ':a;$!{N;ba};s/.*#include[^\n]*/&\n#include <new.h>/' file1 file2 fileN
```